# Selenium: get Last-Modified HTTP header?

Tags: java, http, selenium

Is it possible to check whether a page is old (in that case this page will be skipped by the test) by evaluating the If-Modified-Since HTTP header property of a page?

Is it possible to check this before the page is completely loaded, therefore saving some bandwith and time?

I am using `RemoteWebDriver()`

Comment: `If-Modified-Since` is an http *request* header. Do you mean `Last-Modified`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet might be to use [BrowserMob Proxy](http://proxy.browsermob.com), which is designed to work with Selenium and capture the HTTP traffic taking place during your test. I created BrowserMob Proxy based on the code we developed in Selenium RC (I'm the creator of that) and [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com) (a cloud performance testing service).

Comment: See [https://bmp.lightbody.net/](https://bmp.lightbody.net/) and [https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy#using-with-selenium).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware there's a built-in way to get the header specifically. You can instead use driver.getPageSource() and then parse the HTML with something like JSoup or Jericho.

Alternatively, cast your WebDriver object to a JavascriptExecutor and do this:

```
( (JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.lastModified;");
```

Comment: The HTML source won't contain the HTTP headers

Comment: I assumed he meant lastModified

Comment: It won't contain *any* HTTP headers. +1 for workaround using js document object.

Comment: Will it work? ExecuteScript injects js into the document, so result will be current time. Isn't?